# Syncfusion Javascript and Aspnetboilerplate

Tags: javascript, syncfusion, aspnetboilerplate

I am using [aspnetboilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/) with JQuery. I want to replace the standard DataTables Grid with Syncfusion's DataGrid in order to test possible replacement. I unfortunately have no luck in getting it working correctly.

As a simple test, I am working with the Users App Service.

It is important to note that I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Fetch Remote data from my AppService with paramenters ie, maxResultCount, skip count (ie paging parameters), sorting, and keywords for searching... the standard stuff
2. Simple crud with inline editing (using pop up windows with datatables)
3. Data Export/PDF Export

My main issue is that I cannot get the features as I implemented with Datatables, paging, loading indicator, sorting, filtering/searching.

First I tried to simply use the `abp.services.app.user.GetAll()` with a DataManager, but quickly realised implementing this way is way more complicated then it needs to be, so I implemented the following:

```
class AbpApiAdaptor extends ej.data.WebApiAdaptor {
    processResponse(e) {
        var data = e.result;

        const result = {
            result: data.items,
            count: data.totalCount
        };

        return result;
    }
}

var data = new ej.data.DataManager({
    adaptor: new AbpApiAdaptor({
        requestType: 'POST'
    }),
    url: `${abp.appPath}api/services/app/User/GetAll`,
    query: new ej.data.Query().addParams({
        maxResultCount: 1,
    }),
});

console.log("Data", data);

var grid = new ej.grids.Grid(
    {
        dataSource: data,
        allowPaging: true,
        pageSettings: { pageSize: 10 },
        allowFiltering: true,
        allowGrouping: true,
        loadingIndicator: { indicatorType: 'Shimmer' },
        columns: [...]
    }
);

grid.appendTo('#UsersGrid');
```

Firstly, I need to extend the `WebApiAdaptor` so that I can override `processResponse` to change the response data so that the DataGrid can display it, sure enough, I am getting data in the grid.

**Problems:**
The request being made is a `GET` request. I have tried and failed to set the requestType to `POST`. Tried setting it in the DataManager, and in the Adaptor, no luck. If I add `.executeQuery(new ej.data.Query().take(10)).then((e) =>` to the DataManager, I can modify the results further, but this is not what I want to do as I can do filtering and paging on the server, rather than client side... and including `executeQuery` results in nothing displayed on the grid in anycase... obviously missing something here.

So, I need to make POST requests for 'reading' from the remote source, and collect other info from the DataGrid (paging info, keywords for searching, sorting, etc).

Any example on how to do this will be appreciated, or documentation that can guide me on the right path.